# Connect local computer from remote server

Tags: windows-10, microphone, rdp

I connected to remote server which is based on Ubuntu using windows remote desktop application. Now I want to access camera, microphones and drive folders in remote server. I tried by checking local resources option in remote desktop application but I didn't get any access to camera and microphone. I don't want to access them like hacking way. I want to access them properly. Can anyone help me? Anu suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think you can access another computer's camera and microphone remotely? That would be a severe breach of security and privacy.

Comment: I want to access my local resources in the remote server. What can we do so that remote computer can access my local resources? As both computers connected by remote desktop application. Can we do something in remove computer so that we can access files in local computer? Can this be termed as breach of security? I am trying to access my files by me to remote server.